# One HTML file, and Multiple CSS files in Rails how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one HTML file located in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

I use `<%=yield=>` to render the HTML code from other models.
The problem is that I don't know how to distinguish the CSS code. I have a universal CSS code, but each html file needs a different one.

here is my CSS line in  `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "scaffold" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "welcome_screen/my_CSS.css", :media => "all" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put a named yield in the head of the layout file, then use content_for in your specific view

```
# application.html.erb
<head>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "scaffold" %>
    <%= yield(:head) %>
    # ...
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield %>
    # ...
</body>
```

then your view code

```
# welcome_screen.html.erb
<% content_for(:head) do %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "welcome_screen/my_CSS.css", :media => "all" %>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<%= yield :head %>` in the `<head>` tag in application.html.erb. Later in you views if you need some css file

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "some_uniq.css" %>
<% end %>
```

You can read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield) for better understaning of how `yield` command works.